# Deleting rows using a limit and offset without using IN clause

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-delete, mariadb-10.4

I want to delete rows with an offset, so I am forced to use a nested query since its not support in the raw DELETE clause.

I know this would worked (ID is the primary key):

```
DELETE FROM customers
WHERE ID IN (
    SELECT ID
    FROM customers
    WHERE register_date > '2012-01-01'
    ORDER BY register_date ASC
    LIMIT 5, 10
);
```

However, this is unsupported in my version as I get the error

```
This version of MariaDB doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'.
```

Server version: 10.4.22-MariaDB

What can I do to achieve the same result as above that is supported in my version.

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
ID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
NAME VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
REGISTER_DATE DATETIME NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: Can you tag the exact database you are using ?

Comment: Hi @PaulShan, I have seen that. I will see can I add it in tags...

Comment: Hi @PaulShan, also, one note - it would be nice to select the answer that is correct for you and accept it. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I did not miss something a simple delete with join will do the job...

```
delete customers
from (select *
      from customers
      WHERE register_date > '2012-01-01'
      order by register_date asc
      limit 5, 2) customers2 
join customers on customers.id = customers2.id
```

[Here is a demo for your version of MariaDB](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=1b7304cd6465110b6d74202ea0e3a7ad)

Answer (score 2):

Join the table to a subquery that uses `ROW_NUMBER()` window function to sort the rows and filter the rows that you want to be deleted:

```
DELETE c
FROM customers c
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY register_date) rn
  FROM customers
  WHERE register_date > '2012-01-01'
) t ON t.ID = c.ID
WHERE t.rn > 5 AND t.rn <= 15; -- get 10 rows with row numbers 6 - 15
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=80e2c6297e7bf64fda9e3bacab77c25e).

Comment: What is `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY register_date) rn` this part doing?

Comment: @PaulShan it returns the ranking of a row in a sorted resultset: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/row_number/

Answer (score 1):

You could try assigning a rank to your rows with the [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/row_number/) window function, then catch those rows whose rank position is between 5 and 15.

```
DELETE FROM customers
WHERE ID IN (
    SELECT * 
    FROM (SELECT ID, 
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                     ORDER BY IF(register_date>'2012-01-01', 0, 1)
                              register_date                       ) AS rn
          FROM customers) ranked_ids
    WHERE rn > 4 
      AND rn < 16
);
```

This would safely avoid the use of `LIMIT`, though achieves the same result.

**EDIT**. Doing it with a join.

```
DELETE FROM customers c
INNER JOIN (SELECT ID, 
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                        ORDER BY IF(register_date>'2012-01-01', 0, 1)
                                    register_date                       ) AS rn
                  FROM customers) ranked_ids
            WHERE 
           ) ids_to_delete
        ON c.ID = ids_to_delete.ID
       AND ids_to_delete.rn > 4 
       AND ids_to_delete.rn < 16
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this using a join?

Comment: Sure, I have updated the answer with the join statement. @PaulShan

Comment: What does the `ROW_NUMBER() OVER()` bit do?

Comment: It assigns a incremental number to each row (1,2,3,4,...), where the order it follows is given by the `ORDER BY` clause.